# Impossible to deactivate a Record Type used by an Object

Tags: record-type, deactivate

I'm deactivated a Record Type with Name="All". It return me the error:

> This record type All cannot be deactivated because it is used by the following Objects.

Opportunity.Codice_Account_opp

`IF( Account.RecordType.DeveloperName = "Lead", Account.Codice_Nielsen__c,
IF( Account.RecordType.DeveloperName = "Lead_Personali", Account.Id ,
IF( Account.RecordType.DeveloperName = "Cliente", Account.PARTNER__c,
IF( Account.RecordType.DeveloperName = "Cliente_Cancellato", Account.PARTNER__c,
IF( Account.RecordType.DeveloperName = "Agenzie", Account.PARTNER__c,
IF( Account.RecordType.DeveloperName = "Agenzia_Cancellata", Account.PARTNER__c,
""))))))`

As you can see, that Object does not use the Record Type of the Opportunity, i.e., there is not in that code "Account.RecordType.DeveloperName="All".

So, what happens?

Comment: Just because the record type name is not used in your formula somewhere does NOT mean that is is not active on a given sObject

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The message is telling you that at least one of those objects is used in creating your opportunities and that's why you can't deactivate it.

Comment: At the end I just deleted the content of the class, I deactivated and deleted the button and then I replaced the content of the class.